# Getting certificate for apple push notification service

Tags: api, apple-push-notifications

Do I have to create a paid account on apple's developer program in order to get the certificate for apple push notification service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word and to make this answer long enough to submit: Yes.

Comment: And does apple charges for the push alerts after that.

Comment: Is there any sandbox provided by apple to test it first.

Comment: Ok last question, do i have to create paid account to use the sandbox?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you just peruse the information available from Apple for all this?